# jquery passing function parameters

Tags: jquery, function

I am using the following for a double-tap/single tap of a DOM element.

```
$(selector).doubletap(
     /** doubletap-dblclick callback */
     function(event){          
          var $this = $(event.currentTarget);
     },

     /** touch-click callback (touch) */
     function(event){
         doSingleClick(this)
     },
     /** doubletap-dblclick delay (default is 500 ms) */
     400
);
```

Another function I call from the above :

```
 function doSingleClick(but) {
      var $but = $(but);

      if($but.closest("#domElementId").length < 1)
          return;

      //"I have more code here to handle the if statement"
 }
```

The doSingleClick function never gets past the return b/c the value of $but never gets correctly defined.  My assumption is that I am not passing parameters correctly.  Where is my issue?

Comment: The code looks fine, asumming you wan't $but to contain a jQuery object that wraps the element that was doubletapped.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you pulled this code from here:

http://appcropolis.com/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/

Looking at the code, the functions you are providing to .doubletap() are invoked on an event callback from the browser, without the benefit of the jQuery selector.  The 'this' in:

```
 function(event){
     doSingleClick(this)
 },
```

is likely the Window context, not the element you are expecting.  The simplest approach to fixing it is using the current element as the input:

```
 function(event){
     doSingleClick(event.currentTarget)
 },
```

which is what the doubletap/click function is already doing with the $this = $(event.currentTarget)

Hope that helps.